# Outlook 2011 Mac OSX 10.7.3 search returning no results

Tags: osx-lion, search, microsoft-outlook-2011

An iMac running Mac OSX 10.7.3 and Outlook 2011 14.1.4 is unable to return any search results for mailboxes on the server or locally, contacts, calendar items or tasks.

Spotlight functions normally on the machine.

I am about to follow instructions listed [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/i-am-not-able-to-search-in-outlook-2011-any-search/32b578ea-995a-4c43-af2e-d1ba026593cc?tab=MoreHelp).

Can anyone provide any insight on which of these .plists listed in the article can provide the solution to this issue?